# Заполнение последовательности в зависимости от пороговых значений без цикла

Tags: r

у меня есть пример кода , который ищет в векторе z значения меньше -1,8 и проставляет 1 до тех пор , пока значение вектора z не станет больше 0 иначе заполняет 0. Для этого я использую 2 цикла , что на большом объёме данных происходит очень медленно. Есть ли какие то более продуктивные и простые способы выполнить эту задачу?

```
z <- c(-1,-1.4,-1.1,-1.8,-2.2,-2.5,-1.7,-1,-0.5,-0.1,0.2,0.4)

q <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(z)) {
  if (z[i] <= -1.8) {
    temp <- 1
  }else temp <- 0
  q <- rbind(q, temp)
}

for (i in 2:length(q)) {
  if (z[i] < 0 & q[i-1] == 1) {
    q[i] <- 1
  }
}

q
     [,1]
temp    0
temp    0
temp    0
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    1
temp    0
temp    0
>
```

Answer (score 1):

сводится к классической задаче «заполнение отсутствующих данных предыдущим значением».

вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7735647/4827341) много разных вариантов приведено. есть даже [сравнение их производительности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39304948/4827341).

понятно, что на первом месте [ffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)-функция, написанная на компилируемом языке. но можно взять и следующий по производительности вариант — в ответах функция [названа `na.lomf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23592345/4827341).

т.е., основываясь на ваших данных, имеется вот такой вектор, полученный из исходного:

```
> a
 [1] NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  0  0
```

где значения меньше 1.8 заменены на единицы, а значения больше нуля заменены на нули:

```
> z <- c(-1,-1.4,-1.1,-1.8,-2.2,-2.5,-1.7,-1,-0.5,-0.1,0.2,0.4)
> a <- ifelse(z <= -1.8, 1, ifelse(z > 0, 0, NA))
> a
 [1] NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  0  0
```

применяя к нему ту самую [функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23592345/4827341):

```
# last observation moved forward
# replaces all NA values with last non-NA values
na.lomf <- function(x) {

    na.lomf.0 <- function(x) {
        non.na.idx <- which(!is.na(x))
        if (is.na(x[1L])) {
            non.na.idx <- c(1L, non.na.idx)
        }
        rep.int(x[non.na.idx], diff(c(non.na.idx, length(x) + 1L)))
    }

    dim.len <- length(dim(x))

    if (dim.len == 0L) {
        na.lomf.0(x)
    } else {
        apply(x, dim.len, na.lomf.0)
    }
}
```

получаем (почти) то, что вам требуется:

```
> na.lomf(a)
 [1] NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
```

теперь оставшиеся `NA` можно заменить на требующиеся вам нули [каким-нибудь способом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8161836/4827341).

хотя можно обойтись и без этой замены, требующей доп. вычислений, если заменить первый элемент `a` на ноль *перед* вызовом `na.lomf()`:

```
> a[1] <- 0
```

или, более универсально, заменить на ноль только если там `NA`:

```
> a[1] <- ifelse(is.na(a[1]), 0, a[1])
```

теперь получим уже ровно то, что требуется:

```
> a
 [1]  0 NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  0  0
> na.lomf(a)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```